# Custom filter field test doesn't work

Tags: python, django, testing

I have the next test for a [filter field](https://github.com/JensAstrup/django-jetpack/blob/master/jet/tests/test_filters.py).

Running the test i have this bug:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_related_field_ajax_list_filter (jet.tests.test_filters.FiltersTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/tiempoturco/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jet/tests/test_filters.py", line 42, in test_related_field_ajax_list_filter
    list_filter = RelatedFieldAjaxListFilter(field, request, lookup_params, model, model_admin, field_path)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/tiempoturco/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/filters.py", line 176, in __init__
    self.empty_value_display = model_admin.get_empty_value_display()
TypeError: get_empty_value_display() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

======================================================================
ERROR: test_related_field_ajax_list_filter_with_initial (jet.tests.test_filters.FiltersTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/tiempoturco/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jet/tests/test_filters.py", line 55, in test_related_field_ajax_list_filter_with_initial
    list_filter = RelatedFieldAjaxListFilter(field, request, lookup_params, model, model_admin, field_path)
  File "/home/salahaddin/Proyectos/tiempoturco/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/filters.py", line 176, in __init__
    self.empty_value_display = model_admin.get_empty_value_display()
TypeError: get_empty_value_display() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I can't understand what the problem is, I investigate digging in the filter and I can find the problem: the line 176 in `django`. [admin filters](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/filters.py)

How can I fix this problem, which is the better way for initialize `model_admin` parameter? What's the correct way for make this test?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is higher up, in line 30:

```
    model_admin = ModelAdmin
```

Here you are not instantiating the object, you simply create another reference to the class itself. Calling a method directly on a class will give the error you see.

You need to call the class to instantiate it, passing it any required arguments.